# Getting most recent records using the MAX function and Subquery taking very long and almost impossible to query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to get the most recent record for each user as highlighted in the screenshot below:

```
SELECT * 
FROM RENTAL
WHERE LastVisit = 
   (SELECT Max(T.LastVisit) 
    FROM RENTAL AS T 
    WHERE T.UserID = RENTAL.UserID)
```

[image]

The problem is it takes extremely very long time to get results.

Is there a faster alternative way?

Comment: did you try with joins ? +creating indexes on req columns ?

Comment: or this `select*, max(T.LastVisit) from RENTAL T inner join RENTAL R on T.userid=R.userid group by T.userid,....`

Comment: Is there a primary key in the table?

Comment: Well the user ID is a unique identifier for the User but not a Primary key in that particular table.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `GROUP BY` query which gives you the most recent `LastVist` for each `UserID`.

```sql
SELECT
    T.UserID,
    Max(T.LastVisit) AS MaxOfLastVisit
FROM RENTAL AS T 
GROUP BY T.UserID;
```

If that was correct, use it as a subquery which you join back to `RENTAL`.  The outcome should be filtering `RENTAL` to only those rows which match the subquery rows.

```sql
SELECT R.*
FROM
    RENTAL AS R
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            T.UserID,
            Max(T.LastVisit) AS MaxOfLastVisit
        FROM RENTAL AS T 
        GROUP BY T.UserID
    ) AS sub
    ON
            r.UserID = sub.UserID
        AND r.LastVist = sub.MaxOfLastVisit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this query

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY UserId  ORDER BY LastVisit DESC) rnk,*
FROM  RENTAL
)a
WHERE a.rnk=1
```